# Footer on last page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I begin with LaTeX and use `fancyhdr`. So I've got a sweet footer for all my pages but...I'd like to create one another which would be active on last page only.
This footer will contain my informations and perhaps, some copyrights on my document.

It will be as wide as my page width, like the footer of these several pages :

- http://www.mobilibook.com/
- http://www.centre-equestre-dupin.fr/

A colored band which can be modified easily...
Is this possible ? Can you help me please ?

Comment: Hi Nayou and welcome to the site. It's certainly possible to do that. But can you be more specific about what you want? Maybe post the contents of a small `.tex` file that we can use as a starting point?

Comment: @JohnWickerson : Of course yes.

That's how my .tex begins : 
[link](http://pastie.org/private/89a4wqfyugojskdfi3sa)

Comment: Do you search \vfill?

Comment: You can define a new heading and use it on the last page with `\thispagestyle{foo}`.

Comment: @Sigur : With your way : `\thispagestyle{bar}` that will work on the current page. So, have I to put it after my last `\section` or `\chapter` ?

Comment: If you have an specific page to you personal content, for example, a `\newpage` command, you can use it after this. Make some tests.

Comment: @Nayou, please, see the answer below. You can use `\pagestyle` instead of `\thispagestyle` so it will be used from that page.

Comment: @Sigur : Ok, I tried `\thispagestyle{bar}` after my last `\section` or `\chapter` and it works for my last page. Thanks.
`\thispagestyle{foo}`or `\pagestyle{bar} : both works. Thx

Now, I want to create a shape as wide as the width of my page.
@moose : `\vfill`could be the solution. But how to ask LaTeX to make a regular colored shape on the bottom of this page...

Comment: @Nayou, what do you mean: a rectangular box around the footer?

Comment: @Nayou please see my answer below for a rectangular box that can be easily customizable (width, fill color, etc.), containing arbitray text at the desired positions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be easily done with the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package; the package is loaded with the `pages=some` option, and then `\BgThispage` is used for the page where the declared material should appear:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,angle=0,color=black,
  contents={%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \draw[fill=gray!10,ultra thick,draw=gray,rounded corners] 
    ([yshift=120pt,xshift=5pt]current page.south west) 
    rectangle 
    ([yshift=5pt,xshift=-5pt]current page.south east);
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,text width=.3\paperwidth,align=left] at ([yshift=-20pt,xshift=10pt]current page.south west|-current page text area.south west) {Some information \\ Additional information \\ Some articles};
    \node[anchor=north,inner sep=0pt,text width=.3\paperwidth,align=left] at ([yshift=-20pt,xshift=-25pt]current page text area.south) {Some information \\ Additional information \\ Some articles};
    \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt,text width=.3\paperwidth,align=left] at ([yshift=-20pt,xshift=-10pt]current page.south east|-current page text area.south east) {Some information \\ Additional information \\ Some articles};
  }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]% regular pages
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since some calculations are involved, the code needs two or three runs to stabilize.

Another variant:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,angle=0,color=black,
  contents={%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \fill[gray!70,ultra thick] 
    ([yshift=120pt]current page.south west) 
    rectangle 
    (current page.south east);
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,text width=.3\paperwidth,align=left] at ([yshift=-20pt,xshift=10pt]current page.south west|-current page text area.south west) {Some information \\ Additional information \\ Some articles};
    \node[anchor=north,inner sep=0pt,text width=.3\paperwidth,align=left] at ([yshift=-20pt,xshift=-25pt]current page text area.south) {Some information \\ Additional information \\ Some articles};
    \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt,text width=.3\paperwidth,align=left] at ([yshift=-20pt,xshift=-10pt]current page.south east|-current page text area.south east) {Some information \\ Additional information \\ Some articles};
  }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]% regular pages
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You should include such "end of document" content as part of the `\AtEndDocument` hook, whether it's setting a page style, or adding a box with content. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancypagestyle{default}{
  \fancyhf{}% No header/footer
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}% Right footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% A footer rule
}
\fancypagestyle{last-page}{
  \fancyhf{}% No header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{\fbox{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{Hello world}}}% Centre footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% A footer rule
}
\pagestyle{default}% Default page style
\AtEndDocument{\thispagestyle{last-page}}% Page style at \end{document}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Note that unprocessed floats at the end of the document (if there are any), might cause problems with the placement of the `last-page` style.

---

Similarly, you could use

```
\AtEndDocument{\vfill%
  % Your end-of-document content
}
```

to insert a vertical fill and place your end-of-document content automatically (whatever it may be). The same condition holds for unprocessed end-of-document floats. If this remains a concern, investigate the functionality of the [`atveryend` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend).

Comment: You answered exactly what I needed. Thanks to your solution, I can use my own custom class more easily.

It works. Now, how to ask the rectangle to expand sufficiently to fill the width of my page. A simple \vfill doesn't works for that.

Comment: @Nayou: Do you want the box to be in the text block or in the footer? If the former, should the box span from the end of your text to the bottom of the text block?

Answer (score 4):

Using `\AtEndDocument` is dangerous. It is possible that many pages are output, if `\clearpage` of `\end{document}` is reached. Or the last page is already output, *before* `\end{document}` is called.

A safer method is using a label:

- Package `zref-abspage` provides an absolute page number for the `zref` referencing system.
- Package `zref-lastpage` defines the label `LastPage` that is put into the `.aux` file using the hook `\AfterLastShipout` of package `atveryend`.
- The label can be used inside the macros of package `fancyhdr` to define
  the head and foot lines.
- Macro `\iffancylastpage` hides the internal stuff (asking the label `LastPage`, if the current page is the last page). In version 2013/02/09 v3.0 of `zref-abspage` (not yet released) the interface is simplified at the cost of compatibility. Therefore `\iffancylastpage` is defined both for older and newer versions of `zref-abspage`.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{zref-abspage,zref-lastpage}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{zref-abspage}{2013/02/09}{%
  \newcommand*{\iffancylastpage}{%
    \ifnum\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{abspage}{-1}=\value{zabspage}%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }%
}{%
  \newcommand*{\iffancylastpage}{%
    \ifnum\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{abspage}{-1}%
        =\numexpr\value{abspage}+1\relax
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \iffancylastpage{\textbf{LAST PAGE}}{NORMAL PAGE}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example to show how to define and use a personal header/footer.

Since I don't know if you are using `oneside` or `twoside` option on the class, it is better to define both odd and even.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,a5paper]{geometry}
\makeatletter
 \def\ps@myinfo{
 \def\@oddhead{left \hfill center\hfill right}
 \def\@oddfoot{left \hfill center\hfill right}
 \def\@evenhead{left \hfill center\hfill right}
 \def\@evenfoot{left \hfill center\hfill right}
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage    
\pagestyle{myinfo}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

To use a footer with a rectangle, load the package `calc` and use

```
\def\@oddfoot{\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{left\hfill center \hfill right}}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sigur, I understand and it works. Now I'll search how to choose the width of this rectangle.

Thanks a lot !

NB : Is this possible to use two `\documentclass{}` at the same time ? Or have I to create my own with the desired properties ?

Comment: You can not use two classes. You can create a `.sty` file with your personal commands and load it as a package.