# Beamer : different footline on the last page

Tags: beamer, header-footer

Footline of my beamer presentation contains page numbers. Is it possible to add a different footline to the last frame (something like "this is the last slide") ? Please note that, I am talking about adding the command to the preamble, so that I don't have to manually type the required footline on the last page.

A minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}    
First page    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}    
Last page
Footline - "last slide" is needed here.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I tried this method - [Footer on last page (for article or book class)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120773/footer-on-last-page), which is not working for beamer. Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
        \if\insertframenumber\inserttotalframenumber
            last frame
        \else
            footline of normal slides
        \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}    
First page    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}   
Last page
Footline - "last slide" is needed here.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to modify `\if\insertframenumber\inserttotalframenumber` if I want it to refer to the first (title) frame? Or frame No. 4?

Comment: @Viesturs Why do you want to modify the footline of the titlepage? To remove it?

Comment: Yes. I saw in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18828/how-to-remove-footline-on-the-title-page-of-beamer-slides that one can use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}` in the scope of the titlepage, but I am nevertheless curious how to modify that expression.

Comment: @Viesturs `\if\insertframenumber1`, but such hard codes values are quite inflexible. What if one of your presentations will have no title page or the title page will not be the first slide? I think such a change should be made from within the presentation, e.g. `\begin{frame}[plain] \titlepage \end{frame}`